# Copper FCC structure using ASE (Atomic Simulation Environment) library in python

Tags: density-functional-theory, atomic-simulation-environment, atomistic-simulation, gpaw, computational-frameworks

I want to create a FCC structure using ASE (atomic simulation environment). I have define the all the required parameter correctly but at the time when i add GPAW calculator. The output of the program says that: "Atoms are too close". Please comment on this where i'm wrong.

Code

```
from ase import Atoms

a=4.0 # Lattice constant (in Angstroms)

position=[(0,0,0), (0,0,a), (0,a,0), (a,0,0), (0,a,a), (a,0,a), (a,a,0),(a,a,a), (a/2,0,a/2), (a/2,a,a/2),
         (a/2,a/2,0),(a/2,a/2,a), (0,a/2,a/2),(a,a/2,a/2)]

symbol=['Cu']*len(position)
fcc= Atoms(symbols=symbol, positions=position, cell=(a,a,a), pbc=True)

view(fcc)

print(fcc.symbols)        # Access atomic symbols
#print(fcc.positions)      # Access atomic positions
print(fcc.pbc)            # Access periodic boundary conditiom
print(fcc.get_distance(0,1))    # Access distance between Atom
print(fcc.get_masses())     # Access Mass of Atom
print(fcc.get_cell_lengths_and_angles())  #Access Cell length and Angles
```

For Calculation

```
from gpaw import GPAW, PW

calc = GPAW()
fcc.set_calculator(calc)
```

Comment: Check atomic positions. You need 4 atoms for a conventional FCC unit cell. It is periodic boundary condition.

Comment: It's better if you use the bulk() method from the build module of ASE. The details of this method is given at https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/build/build.html#ase.build.bulk Regards
Punit

Answer (score 7):

First, I want to show a general way of checking the minimum bond length of a structure in ASE. Using your structure as an example, you can get the distance matrix in ASE by [`get_all_distances()`](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/atoms.html#ase.Atoms.get_all_distances):

```
from ase import Atoms

a = 4.0 # Lattice constant (in Angstroms)
position = [(0,0,0), (0,0,a), (0,a,0), (a,0,0), (0,a,a), 
            (a,0,a), (a,a,0),(a,a,a), (a/2,0,a/2), (a/2,a,a/2),
            (a/2,a/2,0),(a/2,a/2,a), (0,a/2,a/2),(a,a/2,a/2)]
symbol = ['Cu']*len(position)
atoms = Atoms(symbols=symbol, positions=position, cell=(a,a,a), pbc=True)
D = atoms.get_all_distances(mic=True) # Use minimum image convention for periodic systems
```

Then you can get the minimum pairwise distance by

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.ones(D.shape, dtype=bool)
np.fill_diagonal(mask, 0)
dmin = D[mask].min()
print(dmin)
```

And you will see the minimum bond length of your structure is 0. Why is that? Because you are using 14 atoms instead of 4 atoms for a conventional fcc unit cell, and there are many atoms overlapping with each other. Remember your cell have periodicity in all 3 dimensions.

The easiest way to build a valid fcc Cu bulk structure given the lattice constant is by using [`ase.build.bulk`](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/build/build.html#ase.build.bulk):

```
from ase.build import bulk

atoms = bulk('Cu', 'fcc', a=4.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you perform DFT calculations under periodic boundary condition(PBC), you should check your structure carefully. The first two atoms `(0, 0, 0)` and `(0, 0, a)` possesses the same coordinate in periodic cube with length `a`.

Considering symmetrically distinct atoms only, your code can be revised as following:

```py
from ase import Atoms

a = 4.0 # Lattice constant (in Angstroms)

position = [(0, 0, 0), (a/2, 0, a/2), (a/2, a/2, 0), (0, a/2, a/2)]

symbols = ['Cu']*len(position)
fcc = Atoms(symbols=symbol, positions=position, cell=(a, a, a), pbc=True)
```

Of course it is way simpler to use `ase.build.bulk` function:

```
import ase.build

atoms = ase.build.bulk('Cu', 'fcc', a=4.0, cubic=True)
```

If you want only primitive unit cell, set `cubic` to `False`.